# How to pass a variable with in jquery to mysql

Tags: jquery

I found this code for the infinite scroll pagination but there is one problem. I can pass a variable from this page going to democontent.php

Could anyone help me with this one? What I need to do is to pass an ID from this code to democontent.php I can't figure out what I have been doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){   
    $('#content').scrollPagination({    
        'contentPage': 'democontent.php', // the page where you are searching for results
        'contentData': {}, // you can pass the children().size() to know where is the pagination
        'scrollTarget': $(window), // who gonna scroll? in this example, the full window
        'heightOffset': 10, // how many pixels before reaching end of the page would loading start? positives numbers only please
        'beforeLoad': function(){ // before load, some function, maybe display a preloader div
            $('#loading').fadeIn(); 
        },
        'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){ // after loading, some function to animate results and hide a preloader div
             $('#loading').fadeOut();
             var i = 0;
             $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
             if ($('#content').children().size() > 0){ // if more than 100 results loaded stop pagination (only for test)
                $('#nomoreresults').fadeIn();
                $('#content').stopScrollPagination();
             }
        }
    });

    // code for fade in element by element with delay
    $.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
        var delay = 0;
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
            delay += 100;
        });
    };

});
</script>
```

Comment: `'contentData': {}` this passes data to the PHP file

Comment: @ManseUK how do you use this? say for example i have an id=39 and i have to pass this value to democontent.php who do i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13346715/572939 <- this shows you how

Comment: Sir @rory mcCrossan has got it right. thanks for the help sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it right there in your question:

```
'contentData': {}, // you can pass the children().size() to know where is the pagination
```

For example:

```
var id = 5;

$('#content').scrollPagination({  
    // other settings
    contentData: { id: id }
});
```

Then in your PHP:

```
$id = $_POST['id']; // = 5
```

Comment: sorry sir. it's that i can't read the way the code was written. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

i use this javascript function to pass a variable from js to php. If you want to use ajax, then you can use this:

```
function showUser()
{
    var combo = document.getElementById("users");
    var uname = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("selectbox2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+uname,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: And all the javascript zealots wonder why people use jQuery for this.